# no puedo enviar email con php

Tags: php, html, formularios

estoy intentando enviar mi formulario por email, pero no lo consigo, he creado la función mail(), pero no me envía el correo. Adjunto código.

```
//Definición de variables
    $asociacion = $_POST['asociacion'];
    $nick = $_POST['jug_nickname'];
    $nombre = $_POST['jug_nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['jug_apellidos'];
    $dni = $_POST['jug_dni'];
    $fechaNacimiento = $_POST['jug_fec_nac'];
    $email = $_POST['jug_e_mail'];;
    $telefono = $_POST['jug_telefono'];
    $duracion = $_POST['duracion_seguro'];
    //$comprobar_dni = comprobar_documento_identificacion($dni);

//PASAMOS A MAYÚSCULAS
$tmy3 = strtoupper($nick);
$tmy3 = strtr($tmy3, "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ", "AEIOUAEIOU");

$tmy2 = strtoupper($nombre);
$tmy2 = strtr($tmy2, "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ", "AEIOUAEIOU");

$tmy2_2 = strtoupper($apellidos);
$tmy2_2 = strtr($tmy2_2, "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ", "AEIOUAEIOU");

//Compongo el cuerpo
    //$cuerpo = "Formulario enviado ".$comprobar_dni."\n"; 
    $cuerpo  = "Asociación que comunica el Alta....: ".$asociacion."\n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Nickname o Apodo del Jugador....: ".$nick."\n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Nombre del Jugador......: ".$nombre."\n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Apellidos del Jugador......: ".$apellidos."\n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "D.N.I. del Jugador....: ".$dni."\n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Fecha de Nacimiento del Jugador....: ".$fechaNacimiento."\n";
    $cuerpo .= "E-Mail del Jugador....: ".$email."\n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Teléfono del Jugador....: ".$telefono."\n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Duración del seguro solicitada...: ".$duracion."\n"; 


//mando el correo's...
//mail("---------","Formulario recibido",$cuerpo);
$para = "daviserraalonso@gmail.com";
$asunto = "Asunto del email";
$mensaje = "Este es mi primer envío de email con PHP";

$correcto = mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje);
if($correcto){
    echo "<center><h3>Email enviado correctamente</h3></center>";
}else{
    echo "<h3>Error al enviar el email, contacte con el servicio técnico</h3>"; 
}
```

**Formulario HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"> 
<head> 
    <title>Formulario de Alta PHP</title> 
    <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body,td,th {
            font-family: Berlin Sans FB;
            font-size: x-large;
        }
        body {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        -->
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>   
</head> 

<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC" text="#000000" link="#000000" vlink="#000000"> 
<p>
  <?php 
    /*Definición de función para comprobar si el DNI es correcto*/
    function comprobar_documento_identificacion($dni){
        if(strlen($dni)<>9) {
            return "Necesarios 9 dígitos";
        }    

        $dni = strtoupper($dni);

        $letra = substr($dni, -1, 1);
        $numero = substr($dni, 0, 8);

        // Si es un NIE hay que cambiar la primera letra por 0, 1 ó 2 dependiendo de si es X, Y o Z.
        $numero = str_replace(array('X', 'Y', 'Z'), array(0, 1, 2), $numero);   

        $modulo = $numero % 23;
        $letras_validas = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
        $letra_correcta = substr($letras_validas, $modulo, 1);

        if($letra_correcta != $letra) {
            return "Letra incorrecta, la letra debería ser la $letra_correcta.";
        } else {
            return "DNI o NIE OK";
        }
    }

    //Definición de variables
    $asociacion = $_POST['asociacion'];
    $nick = $_POST['jug_nickname'];
    $nombre = $_POST['jug_nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['jug_apellidos'];
    $dni = $_POST['jug_dni'];
    $fechaNacimiento = $_POST['jug_fec_nac'];
    $email = $_POST['jug_e_mail'];;
    $telefono = $_POST['jug_telefono'];
    $duracion = $_POST['duracion_seguro'];
    $comprobar_dni = comprobar_documento_identificacion($dni);

    /*
        function validar_fecha_espanol($fecha){
            $valores = explode('/', $fecha);
            if(count($valores) == 3 && checkdate($valores[1], $valores[0], $valores[2])){
                return "Fecha OK";
            }else{
                return "Fecha Incorrecta";
            }
        }
    */  



?>

<img src="../fada/images/blanco_500x10.jpg" width="500" height="10"/>
  <div align="left">
    <span class="Estilo3">
        Antes de enviarlo, compruebe que los datos introducidos son correctos,
        Si algun dato no es correcto, puede modificarlo antes de enviarlo.
    </hr>
    </span>

    <form id="formularioComprobacion" method="post" action="envioEmail.php">
        Asociacion: <input type="text" size="30" id="asociacion" value="<?php echo $asociacion; ?>"/>
        </br>
        Nick: <input type="text" id="jug_nickname" value="<?php echo $nick; ?>"/>
        </br>
        Nombre: <input type="text" id="jug_nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>"/>
        </br>
        Apellidos: <input type="text" id="jug_apellidos" value="<?php echo $apellidos; ?>"/>
        </br>
        DNI: <input type="text" id="jug_dni" value="<?php echo $dni; ?>"/>
        </br>
        Fecha Nacimiento: <input type="text" id="jug_fec_nac" value="<?php echo $fechaNacimiento; ?>"/>
        </br>
        Email: <input type="text" id="jug_e_mail" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/>
        </br>
        Telefono: <input type="text" id="jug_telefono" value="<?php echo $telefono; ?>"/>
        </br>
        Duracion: <input type="text" id="duracion_seguro" size="30" value="<?php echo $duracion; ?>"/>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Confirmar"/>
    </form>
  </div>

<img src="../fada/images/blanco_500x10.jpg" width="500" height="10"/>

<td>
    <div align="left">
        <img src="../fada/images/blanco_150x175.jpg" width="125" height="175"/>
        <img src="../fada/images/logo_250_01.jpg" width="250" height="175"/>
    </div>
</td>


<img src="../fada/images/blanco_500x10.jpg" width="500" height="10"/>

  <div align="left">
    <span class="Estilo3">
        Gracias por utilizar el Servicio de Alta de Federados
    </span>
  </div>
</p>

  <div align="left">
    <form name="form3" method="post" action="">
        <label>
        </label>
        <img src="../fada/images/blanco_25x15.jpg" width="25" height="15"/>
        <img src="../fada/images/blanco_25x15.jpg" width="25" height="15"/>
        <img src="../fada/images/blanco_25x15.jpg" width="25" height="15"/>
        <img src="../fada/images/blanco_25x15.jpg" width="25" height="15"/>
        <img src="../fada/images/blanco_25x15.jpg" width="25" height="15"/>
        <a href="fadaaltaseguro03.htm"><img src="../faga/imagenes/iconos/icono10.jpg" width="175" height="25" border="0"/></a>
    </form>
  </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

**Archivo PHP**

```html
<?php
/* En este documento, se declara todo lo necesario para el envío del email, con los datos */

    //Definición de variables
        $asociacion = $_POST['asociacion'];
        $nick = $_POST['jug_nickname'];
        $nombre = $_POST['jug_nombre'];
        $apellidos = $_POST['jug_apellidos'];
        $dni = $_POST['jug_dni'];
        $fechaNacimiento = $_POST['jug_fec_nac'];
        $email = $_POST['jug_e_mail'];;
        $telefono = $_POST['jug_telefono'];
        $duracion = $_POST['duracion_seguro'];
        //$comprobar_dni = comprobar_documento_identificacion($dni);

    //PASAMOS A MAYÚSCULAS
    $tmy3 = strtoupper($nick);
    $tmy3 = strtr($tmy3, "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ", "AEIOUAEIOU");

    $tmy2 = strtoupper($nombre);
    $tmy2 = strtr($tmy2, "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ", "AEIOUAEIOU");

    $tmy2_2 = strtoupper($apellidos);
    $tmy2_2 = strtr($tmy2_2, "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ", "AEIOUAEIOU");

    //Compongo el cuerpo
        //$cuerpo = "Formulario enviado ".$comprobar_dni."\n"; 

        $cuerpo  = "Asociación que comunica el Alta....: ".$asociacion."\n"; 
        $cuerpo .= "Nickname o Apodo del Jugador....: ".$nick."\n"; 
        $cuerpo .= "Nombre del Jugador......: ".$nombre."\n"; 
        $cuerpo .= "Apellidos del Jugador......: ".$apellidos."\n"; 
        $cuerpo .= "D.N.I. del Jugador....: ".$dni."\n"; 
        $cuerpo .= "Fecha de Nacimiento del Jugador....: ".$fechaNacimiento."\n";
        $cuerpo .= "E-Mail del Jugador....: ".$email."\n"; 
        $cuerpo .= "Teléfono del Jugador....: ".$telefono."\n"; 
        $cuerpo .= "Duración del seguro solicitada...: ".$duracion."\n";    

    //mando el correo's...

    $para = "------------";
    $asunto = "Asunto del email";
    $mensaje = "Este es mi primer envío de email con PHP";

    $correcto = mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje);
    if($correcto){
        echo "<center><h3>Email enviado correctamente</h3></center>";
    }else{
        echo "<h3>Error al enviar el email, contacte con el servicio técnico</h3>"; 
    }

?>
```

a parte de eso, cuando cargo en el navegador este documento, me dice que no tengo los index definidos y no se como solventar este aviso, sin quitarlos del php.ini

gracias, feliz año y un saludo

Comment: Por favor, añade el código del formulario html que se envía y el mensaje de error literal que recibes.

Comment: Intenta usar PHPmailer, te ahorra algunos problemas

Comment: Quizá el problema  mayor sea que los valores no están siendo recibidos. Si no recibes por ejemplo la dirección de email del destinatario adecuadamente es imposible que el mensaje se envíe. Deberías entonces revisar el código desde el cual supuestamente se deben tomar los datos, el cual no compartes en la pregunta y eso dificulta más poder ayudar.

Comment: gracias por responder a los tres, ya he añadido el código de mis tres archivos

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no me devulve ningún error ya, he conseguido quitar los notice, pero no me envía el email

Comment: ¿Lo estas probando en tu servidor local? Si no tienes un servidor de correo instalado y configurado no funcionará.

Comment: @OscarDíaz hola oscar, en Local, con xampp está el mercury y supuestamente, desde mercury me envía los email, porque lo he probado, pero con php no. Lo que he hecho ha sido subirlo a mi hosting y ahí sin problemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era, subir a un hosting el archivo php, así manda correctamente el email